# pgadmin internal server error: "edit mode types multi.sql" (columns/sql/#90624#)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

does anyone know how to solve this problem with pgadmin?

I get the message:

> Error retriving properties - Internal server error:
> columns/sql/#90624#/edit_mode_types_multi.sql

The message occurs randomly when I try to execute context-menu entries in my databasetree (e.g. Properties of tables, create script, etc.)

Thanks for any advice :-)